# ggplot selecting parts of data as y variable or confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have data taken from some complex analysis in another program that I want to plot using R. I have an X variable and multiple Y variables and predicted confidence limits. I wish to plot them in R in the format of Y vs X with shaded confidence intervals. I know I can subset ggplot to only show main effects - I also know alternatively how to ggplot shaded areas - but I cannot work out how to do both at the same time from the same dataframe.

Example code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

demo <- data.frame(cbind(
            ID = c(1:10),
            X = c(5.00, 1.03, 1.26, 2.03, 0.99, 4.24, 5.00, 5.00, 2.83, 5.00),
            Y1 = c(0.17, 0.84, 0.79, 0.59, 0.85, 0.22, 0.17, 0.17, 0.40, 0.17),
            Y1_lci = c(0.16, 0.81, 0.76, 0.56, 0.82, 0.22, 0.16, 0.16, 0.39, 0.16),
            Y1_uci = c(0.18, 0.87, 0.82, 0.61, 0.88, 0.23, 0.18, 0.18, 0.41, 0.18),
            Y2 = c(0.14, 0.85, 0.80, 0.59, 0.86, 0.20, 0.14, 0.14, 0.38, 0.14),
            Y2_lci = c(0.11, 0.83, 0.77, 0.54, 0.84, 0.16, 0.11, 0.11, 0.33, 0.11),
            Y2_uci = c(0.19, 0.88, 0.83, 0.64, 0.88, 0.25, 0.19, 0.19, 0.44, 0.19)))

demo.melt <- melt(demo, id.vars=c("ID", "X"), value.name="value", variable.name="var")
```

Now I can plot them all as lines like this :

```
ggplot(demo.melt, aes(x=X, y=value, group=var, col=var)) + geom_line()
```

...but that is not what I want. Alternatively I could subset to only the main response variables:

```
demo.sub <- demo.melt[demo.melt$var %in% c("Y1", "Y2"),]
ggplot(demo.sub, aes(x=X, y=value, group=var, col=var)) + geom_line()
```

...but then the CI data is not in the object and I can't/don't know how to plot that using geom_ribbon(). So my question is how to I plot my Y1 & Y2 as lines, and the lci & uci data as bounds for shaded areas at the same time/from the same object ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you melt your data when you have everything in the first dataset as columns? Just try to modify the ggplot code a bit:

```
ggplot(demo, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Y1), color="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=Y2), col="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Y1_lci, ymax=Y1_uci), color="red", alpha=0.2)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Y2_lci, ymax=Y2_uci), color="blue", alpha=0.2)
```

There's a chance that this might look ugly if you do 3+ columns.
So, you might prefer this version to plot side by side:

```
library(gridExtra)

plot1=
ggplot(demo, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Y1), color="red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Y1_lci, ymax=Y1_uci), alpha=0.2)

plot2=
ggplot(demo, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Y2), col="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Y2_lci, ymax=Y2_uci), alpha=0.2)


grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

Also, change `ncol` to `nrow` inside `grid.arrange` if it looks better.

This is if you want to include a legend (in this case it is "manually" created when in the other data format you get it much easier).

```
   ggplot(demo, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Y1, color="Y1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Y2, color="Y2")) +
  labs(title="TITLE", x="X_name", y="Y_name", col="Y")+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Y1_lci, ymax=Y1_uci), col="red", alpha=0.2)+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Y2_lci, ymax=Y2_uci), col="blue", alpha=0.2)
```

There could be a better way of the legend creation, but I've been using this.

To use linetypes:

```
ggplot(demo, aes(x=X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Y1, linetype="Y1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Y2, linetype="Y2")) +
  labs(title="TITLE", x="X_name", y="Y_name", linetype="Y")
```

Comment: Honestly I didn't know you could do it this way - anytime I have looked up plotting multiple variables in one plot in ggplot it says to melt the data and use the group option. Thanks very much.

Comment: Better and more useful to melt data when all columns in your dataset (demo dataset here) represent something different (different variables), but in your case some of them were CIs of others.

Comment: Actually - one thing - plotting this way my graph does not have a legend - how can I add one in ?

Comment: thanks....one last q I promise - I have made one line solid and the other dashed and I'm trying to mod the legend to be the same using `   scale_linetype_manual(name="Y", values = c("solid", "dashed")` - but it isn't affecting the graph legend - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've just changed something. Better to set colours and set titles (axes, graph title and legend) separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `melt` / `reshape`, which is useful if you easily want to generate a legend. Use the `varying` argument of `reshape` to group relevant variables together.

```
demo_m <-  reshape(demo, idvar=c("ID","X"), 
                         varying=list(c(3,6), c(4,7), c(5,8)), 
                         direction="long", 
                         v.names=c("Y", "lci", "uci"))
```

and then plot

```
ggplot(demo_m, aes(X, Y, ymin=lci, ymax=uci, col=factor(time))) + 
              geom_line() + 
              geom_ribbon(alpha=0.2)
```

this also allows you to facet

```
ggplot(demo_m, aes(X, Y, ymin=lci, ymax=uci, col=factor(time))) + 
              geom_line() + 
              geom_ribbon(alpha=0.2) +
              facet_grid(time ~ .)
```

Comment: Thank you also for this answer, although I prefer the other answer since I then have individual control over the aesthetics of each curve.

Comment: youre welcome... you can get control of the scales of individual curves, for example, by using `scale_colour_manual` etc